# loading image accurately in imageview of app's activity

Tags: java, android, imageview, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

I am trying to implement an app where a huge numbers of images are to be loaded in image view on creating the activity--There is exactly 24 imageviews aligned in a scrollview.
When I start that activity with 24 imageview as launcher activity itself-it works fine..
But, when I use that activity as the 2nd activity after a welcome screen it crashes and says ->

```
    12-29 11:54:04.624 31595-31595/com.example.myvidapp W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 6822556 byte allocation with 3024640 free bytes and 2MB until OOM"
12-29 11:54:04.633 31595-31595/com.example.myvidapp D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
12-29 11:54:04.634 31595-31595/com.example.myvidapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-29 11:54:04.635 31595-31595/com.example.myvidapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.myvidapp, PID: 31595
                                                                      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 6822556 byte allocation with 3024640 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
                                                                          at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
                                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
                                                                          at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
                                                                          at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
                                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                                                                          at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4202)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:155)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                          at com.example.myvidapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6723)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1485)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6195)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

HOW CAN i OVERCOME THIS ERROR ??

Here is my xml file ->

```
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:background="@drawable/bkg">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Video Chat MadeEasy"
        android:textColor="#191fcc"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Most Popular collections!!"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/skype"
            android:tooltipText="Skype"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="skype_clk" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/whapp"
            android:tooltipText="WhatsApp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="whp_clk">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/msng"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="msg_clk"
            android:tooltipText="Messenger">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/imo"
            android:tooltipText="imo"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="imo_clk">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/line"
            android:tooltipText="Line"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="lin_clk">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tango"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="tng_clk"
            android:tooltipText="Tango">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/viber"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="vbr_clk"
            android:tooltipText="Viber">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/icq"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="icq_clk"
            android:tooltipText="icq">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/wechat"
            android:tooltipText="weChat"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="wct_clk">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ghangout"
            android:tooltipText="Hangout"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="ght_clk">
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/duo"
            android:onClick="duo_clk"
            android:tooltipText="Duo"></ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bigo"
            android:tooltipText="Bigo Live"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="bgo_clk">
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="More from us!!"
                android:textColor="#191fcc"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Untraditional collections!!"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/snct"
                    android:tooltipText="Snapchat"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="snct_clk" >
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/livu"
                    android:tooltipText="LivU"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="livu_clk">

                </ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/kct"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="kct_clk"
                    android:tooltipText="KingsChat">

                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/lly"
                    android:tooltipText="live.ly"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="lly_clk">

                </ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/mpl"
                    android:tooltipText="Marcopolo"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="mpl_clk">

                </ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/now"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="now_clk"
                    android:tooltipText="YouNow">

                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/lme"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="lme_clk"
                    android:tooltipText="live.me">

                </ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/sgo"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="sgo_clk"
                    android:tooltipText="Streamgo">

                </ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/hny"
                    android:tooltipText="Honey"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="hny_clk">

                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/mln"
                    android:tooltipText="Melon"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="mln_clk">
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/imn"
                    android:onClick="imn_clk"
                    android:tooltipText="Indian Messsenger"></ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/hk"
                    android:tooltipText="Hike"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:onClick="hk_clk">
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Want to explore more ? Click here !!"
        android:onClick="btnpl"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

AND here is the line no 15 which it is showing error -i.e on the "onCreate"->

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //line no 15 in my code(indicated in the logcat)
}
```

Comment: Its coming because you are using many images, try using 
android:largeHeap="true" in application tag in Manifest file, then check.

Comment: You can use Glide or Picasso to load image those libraries will take care of Memory issues

Comment: do you run this program in emulator???

Comment: android:largeHeap="true"  worked,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in your manifest :

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add manifest file android:hardwareAccelerated="false" , android:largeHeap="true" it will work for some environment's.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use image loading libraries like `Glide` and `Picasso`. For `Glide`:

```
public static void loadToGlide(Context context, ImageView imageView, Object o) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .centerCrop())
                .transition(new BitmapTransitionOptions()
                        .crossFade())
                .load(o)
                .into(imageView);
    }
```

To call:

```
loadToGlide(context, yourImageView, R.drawable.yourImage);
```

They will handle everything for you, especially `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recylerview instead of multiple imagviews and can use volley imageloader or glide for image loading seamlessely.